# How do the protection diodes actually protect the supplies in this case?

Tags: power-supply, diodes, reverse-polarity

Regarding making a dual supply from two single supplies, I see two Schottky diodes are placed between the supply terminals in reverse biased way as in the following example I drew.  The diodes are randomly chosen by me just for illustration, so they might not be sized correctly:

[image]

The reasoning behind using such diodes is given as: "The diodes also prevent possible reverse voltage damage if one power supply is off while the others are on."

When I remove  PSU1 in the above schematic or make its voltage to zero and simulate it, I don't see any difference such as excessive current etc. I have spent several hours searching for a detailed explanation but couldn't find any.

Can someone show how in a scenario the diodes protect the supplies by maybe simulating or if not by showing the routes of the currents?

Comment: In this scenario, the diodes don't do anything of note. Are you asking about this specific circuit, or about any possible circuit?

Comment: Any possible scenario with two smps or linear supply along with such protection diodes. I see it many places they use the schottky diodes as in the schematic. Im trying to understand the logic behind it. How they protect the supllies. Many say they are for reverse protection but I cannot figure out how actually and in what case.

Comment: Try a single 200 ohm load with no common ground.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider power supplies that are more realistic- current-limited, with asymmetric limits and only able to source current. And a load across the pair.

[image]

Without the diodes, the negative supply experiences a large reversal at power-up. With the diodes, the reversal is largely prevented.

A similar thing would happen if the supply was overloaded.

Answer (score -1):

This diode configuration relies on having a fuse, PTC or other protective device upstream (i.e. on the supply side).  If the supply is reversed then the fuse will blow and the circuit downstream of the diode will only see a small reverse voltage, which is typically survivable.